# Move WSL2 file system to another drive

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

As opposed to in WSL1, official docs for WSL2 state clearly that I should [place files I access frequently from Linux under the Linux file system](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-ux-changes#place-your-linux-files-in-your-linux-root-file-system). However, I have not found any docs on settings for where inside the Windows file system the Linux file system is placed.

Of course, the default location (somewhere under `%LOCALAPPDATA%`) is suboptimal if you - like me - have your machine configured to have a minimal `C:\` drive and a much larger `D:\` - I would much rather place the Linux file system there, to make use of all that space.

Can I somehow control where my Linux file system is placed?

Comment: Please post, if and when, you find the answer/solution to this issue.

Comment: I haven't found anything better than @Daniel B's answer, but that has actually worked. I even got Docker Desktop working fine with the `docker-desktop-data` distro on D:\ :)

Comment: @Constantine: See above.

Comment: You can also install directly to the D drive if desired: https://superuser.com/questions/1572834/is-there-any-way-to-install-wsl-on-non-c-drive

Answer (score 21, accepted):

(I don’t have WSL 2 to try.)

WSL supports exporting and importing distributions, like this:

```
wsl --export Debian C:\temp\Debian.tar
wsl --import MovedDebian C:\WSL\Debian C:\temp\Debian.tar --version 2
```

Note how I can specify a parameter called `InstallLocation` (`C:\WSL\Debian`). Keep in mind that in my example, the “Debian” distribution still exists, so I select a different name when importing. You can use the `wsl` utility to manage your WSL environments.

Answer (score 119):

If you want to move WSL2 Linux distro(Ubuntu) from C: drive D: below are the steps.

**Export Ubuntu**

- mkdir D:\backup
- wsl --export Ubuntu D:\backup\ubuntu.tar

**Unregister the same distribution to remove it from the C: drive:**

- wsl --unregister Ubuntu

**Import Ubuntu**

- mkdir D:\wsl
- wsl --import Ubuntu D:\wsl\ D:\backup\ubuntu.tar

**By default Ubuntu will use root as the default user, to switch back to previous user**

*Go to the Ubuntu App Folder run command to set default user*

- cd %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
- ubuntu config --default-user <username>

Comment: Just wanted to mention, I initially tried moving the LocalState folder to another drive and using a junction. Obviously it worked, but any incoming updates to the distribution from the Windows Store were a threat to it. So I ended up doing this. This is the long-term sustainable solution.

Comment: I confirm it still works in 2021. Maybe the ubuntu executable on your system is slightly different, like "ubuntu2004" in my case. Another small detail is that if you have docker installed, there might be some other images installed. Use command wsl --set-default Ubuntu-20.04 to set the default again.

Comment: I've done this to put WSL on an external SSD. Anyway I can "register" or import this onto other machines I plug the SSD into? I don't want to run an export everytime I unplug and import on another machine.

Comment: After importing, the wsl file system  was blocked for some reason with message, some other process was still using it and I could not find out which one. So I just restarted Windows and it worked well after.

Comment: You can configure the default user by editing the `/etc/wsl.conf` file within the guest VM, as [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config) describes.

Comment: Best answer! better than selected one

Comment: I arrived here because my WSL2 guest system filled up my smallish C drive so I needed to move it to the much larger D. If this happened to you, make sure to switch your Powershell working directory to D: before attempting a wsl --export command. It will keep failing if it attempts to write temp files to full C drive. Change to the target drive first and you'll more likely succeed.

Comment: Has anyone tried it with Docker for Desktop? It seems to take a lot of space. I wonder, will I break it if I try the same trick with it.

Comment: If you encounter the `Unspecified error Error code: Wsl/Service/E_FAIL` error when using this method, try using a relative path after navigating to the D drive as suggested in [this issue comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4735#issuecomment-1437996023).

Comment: I lost all my user data and installations and everything. Please always mention such issues so, that users can take measures in advance!!!

Comment: For anyone having trouble with the command `ubuntu config --default-user <username>` reinstalling the distro rather than actually setting the default user, see the 'undocumented method' in this comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1566022/how-to-set-default-user-for-manually-installed-wsl-distro#1566031

Note that you can get your uid from WSL by running `cat /etc/passwd | grep <username>`. Your uid is the first 4 digit number -- usually 1000 for WSL.

Comment: In addition to the above, you can also run this one-liner in Powershell as admin:
`$DISTRO_NAME = 'Ubuntu'; $USER_ID = '1000'; Get-ChildItem HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\ | ? { $_.GetValue("DistributionName") -eq $DISTRO_NAME } | Select-Object -First 1 | Set-ItemProperty -Name 'DefaultUid' -Value $USER_ID` specifying the name of your distro in `DISTRO_NAME` and your uid in `USER_ID`

Answer (score 20):

This is an example with ubuntu18.04.
There was couple places the above wasn't detailed enough. Hopefully, this helps.

```
wsl --list --verbose
mkdir d:\backuplinux
wsl --export Ubuntu-18.04 d:\backuplinux\ubuntu.tar
wsl --unregister Ubuntu-18.04
mkdir d:\wsl
wsl --import Ubuntu-18.04 d:\wsl\ d:\backuplinux\ubuntu.tar
cd %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps            **(this is not needed if in path)**
ubuntu1804.exe config --default-user yourloginname
```

Answer (score 12):

In the same spirit, this is an example with ubuntu20.04 on Windows 10.
It was tested on my desktop. It saved 30GB on my C drive.

The Ubuntu disk is located at %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages
CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04onWindows_...\LocalState\ext4.

First, shutdown wsl and confirm the name.

```
wsl --shutdown
wsl --list --verbose

  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04    Stopped         2
```

Then you can export the tar file and import it to D drive:

```
mkdir d:\backuplinux
wsl --export Ubuntu-20.04 d:\backuplinux\ubuntu.tar
wsl --unregister Ubuntu-20.04
mkdir d:\wsl
wsl --import Ubuntu-20.04 d:\wsl\ d:\backuplinux\ubuntu.tar
ubuntu2004.exe config --default-user yourloginname
```

Check d:\wsl, the ext4 file is moved here. Also check the free space on your C drive. You should see a big difference.

Answer (score 10):

The latest versions of WSL2 include a new `wsl --import --vhd` option to directly copy the existing VHD (virtual SDD drive for your WSL2 distribution) to another location.  Note that this will only work with WSL2 distributions, not WSL1.

Also note that it is important to pick a *new*, different name for the copied distribution.  For instance, if your distribution is "Ubuntu", the new name could be "my_Ubuntu" (I call mine "ntd_Ubuntu").

Exit WSL (and, if you use it, shut down Docker Desktop), then from PowerShell (a regular, non-admin terminal):

```
wsl --shutdown

# Find the location of the existing distribution:

Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\ | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        (Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPATH) | Select-Object DistributionName,BasePath 
    }

# Copy the <BasePath> of the distribution you want to copy 
# to the clipboard so that you can paste it into the --import command
# below.

# Create a directory on the other drive for the distro
mkdir d:\WSL\distros\<new_distro_name>

wsl --import <new_distro_name> d:\WSL\distros\<new_distro_name> <BasePath>\ext4.vhdx --vhd
```

WSL will create a new distribution named `<new_distro_name>` in the directory on `D:`.

You can start this distribution with:

```
wsl ~ -d <new_distro_name>
```

Because it is a new distribution, WSL needs to be told what the default username is.  In the meantime, it will start as the root user.  Use [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1627461/1210833) to create a `/etc/wsl.conf` file to specify the default user.

When you are satisfied that the new distribution is working the same as the old, you can remove the old with:

```
# Warning: This is a destructive and unrecoverable operation
# Please ensure the correct distribution name
wsl --unregister <old_distro_name>
```

You can set the new distribution as default with:

```
wsl --set-default <new_distro_name>
```

Comment: you can also rename it first or afterwards if you want to keep the name with regedit under `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\...` and set `DistrubutionName` accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

I have found an approach that does not require deleting (unregistering) and importing an existing distibution.

1. Stop the distribution you want to relocate: `wsl --terminate Ubuntu` or `wsl --shutdown`.
2. Create a backup, just to be sure: `wsl --export Ubuntu` D:\Ubuntu-backup.tar`.
3. Start the Registry Editor (`regedit.exe` - it requires elevated permissions).
4. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\`. Here, you can find all the existing distributions. Find the one that you want to relocate based on the `DistributionName` entry (in my case, it is `Ubuntu`).
5. The `BasePath` entry shows the current location of the disk. In my case: `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState`. If you open this folder, you will see that it has one `ext4.vhdx` file. This is the disk file.
6. Copy this file to the location where you want to have it. For example, `cp C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx D:\wsl\Ubuntu\`.
7. Change the `BashPath` entry in Registry Editor to point to this new location.
8. Just start the WSL distribution, it will use the disk in the new location. At this point, you can delete the disk file from the original location.

Comment: It works good. 
Like my case, First file location has changed, then this will be the easy solution.

Answer (score 2):

Cross post from [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1732559/209060)

1. wsl --terminate distro_name
2. move the ext4.vhdx file to new_location
3. wsl --unregister distro_name
4. wsl --import-in-place distro_name ext4.vhdx_file_in_new_location

Note you need to be on the latest version, but I can verify that this works.

Answer (score 0):

Note that after completing the accepted answer, you need to set Ubuntu as default distro and start it up again. Otherwise, the system will default to Docker.

Here is how to do it:

```
$ wsl --set-default Ubuntu
$ wsl -d Ubuntu
```