# How to set default user for manually installed WSL distro?

Tags: linux, windows, user-accounts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have cloned a WSL distro using `wsl --export` and `wsl --import`, but now, running `wsl newdistro` always logs me in as root. I understand that the `lxrun` command is deprecated and want to avoid it. The docs recommend using `distroname.exe config`, but that doesn't work, since this one doesn't have a corresponding executable.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

As of the time of this writing, there are at least three (let's call it 3.5) different methods of changing/setting the default user in an imported WSL instance.  While the two that have already been mentioned still work, there is a Microsoft recommended way to do it that hasn't been mentioned yet in this question.

#### Method 1 - `/etc/wsl.conf`

The current [Microsoft recommended](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#user-settings) way of setting the username in an instance is to create a `/etc/wsl.conf` in the instance with the following setting:

```
[user]
default=username
```

Changing, of course, username to be your default username.

Exit your distro/instance, then issue a `wsl --terminate <distroname>` from PowerShell or CMD.  When you restart, the default user should be set.

This is safer and less error-prone than the registry-based methods.

#### Method 2 - Registry Key

Setting the registry key per @harrymc's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1566031/1210833).

#### Method 3 - LxRunOffline

Using [LxRunOffline](https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline) to set the registry entry, as described in @Jaime's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1627405/1210833).  Ultimately this has the same effect as Method 2.

#### Semi-method 4 - Runtime user selection via `wsl` commandline argument

The username can be selected when starting any WSL instance by:

`wsl -u username` or `wsl -d distroname -u username`, etc.

For instance, `wsl -d Ubuntu -u root`.

---

Side Note: This question was specifically about setting the default username in an *imported* instance.
However, for completeness, you can also set the default username for a distro that was installed from the Store (or `wsl --install`) with:

```
<distro>.exe config --default-user <username>
```

For instance, if you installed "Ubuntu 20.04" from the Store, you would use:

```
ubuntu2004.exe config --default-user <username>
```

The `.exe` here is an "App Execution Alias" in Windows.  You can check the name by going to *"Manage app execution aliases"* in the Windows System Settings.

---

#### For readers who need to create a new user

*@ndemou made a good point in the comments last year that I, in hindsight, dismissed improperly.  Two other users have now mentioned in the comments that @ndemou's information was helpful.  My belated apologies!  Here's the additional information based on @ndemou's advice ...*

Some users who find this answer may be starting up as root not because they `--import`'d a distribution, but possibly because the default user was never created during installation in the first place.  This can happen when the distribution installation is stopped prematurely, and likely for other reasons as well.

Under Ubuntu, the default distribution for WSL, you can create your user by starting with:

```
wsl ~ -u root
```

If you need to, add the `-d <distribution>` option.

Then run:

```
NEWUSER=<your_username>
useradd --create-home --shell /usr/bin/bash --user-group --groups  adm,dialout,cdrom,floppy,sudo,audio,dip,video,plugdev,netdev --password $(read -sp Password: pw ; echo $pw | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) $NEWUSER
```

Then set the user as the default using the `/etc/wsl.conf` as mentioned above.

If you've already created the user, or are using a different distribution, as @ndemou points out, make sure to also add the user either to a group that is in `sudoers` or directly to `sudoers` via `visudo`.  See the answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18830/432493) for additional details.

Comment: You may want to add the new user to sudoers. If you forget it start wsl as root with something like `wsl --list; wsl --distribution Ubuntu-22.04 -u root`

Comment: @ndemou Since this question is about a `wsl --export`'d distro, then the user in the `wsl --import`'d one will still be in `sudoers` -- No need to add it again.

Comment: you are absolutely right.  However it doesn't hurt to leave the comment for those like me that came here by googling and are not at the exact same situation.

Comment: @ndemou I just realized -- If you had to add the user to `sudoers` in Ubuntu 22.04, then you may not have created the user correctly.  Under 22.04, the normal groups that the WSL user should be in are `adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lxd` (other than the `$USER` group, of course).  As long as your user is in the `sudo` group, the default `sudoers` file will give you access without needing to edit it.

Comment: adding the entry to /etc/wsl.conf to set the default user does not appear to be working for me

Comment: @MattWarren You did `wsl --terminate` after, right?  Troubleshooting recommendations - Do a `wsl -l -v` to check that the default distribution is what you expect it to be.  Do a `su - <username>` as root and confirm that you can change to that user manually.

Comment: Yep. no matter what I tried it ignored the entry in /etc/wsl.conf.

I ended up using the -u option in the windows terminal profile that I use to launch a shell in the distro  (ie: semi-method 4 above)

Comment: Thanks for the inclusion of `-u`.  This answer is applicable to many more people than just imported distros.  A coworker somehow installed Ubuntu without a user, so everything was defaulting to `root`.  Created a user for him and then it all went to hell when we forgot to add him as a sudoer before setting his default user.  So @ndemou, greatly appreciate the answer.

Comment: Thanks @UtahJarhead, and apologies to ndemou for not including this when you originally pointed out that it could be helpful.

Comment: The first method has worked for me as of 04/07/2023 for Ubuntu-22.04.

Comment: @MattWarren I forgot `default=` before the username. Maybe you forgot that, too?

Answer (score 40):

The normal  command syntax is for example:

```
ubuntu config --default-user new_user_name
```

However, this does not work for an imported distro, which is started
by the following command :

```
wsl --distribution <DistributionName>
```

Try this undocumented method:

- Use `regedit` and navigate to the key:
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss`
- Examine its subkeys for a distribution that has the right name in the
  item `DistributionName`
- Create or modify a DWORD item named `DefaultUid` and set it to the
  user-id (uid) of your default user.
  Here root user is id `0` while the first user id is 1000 (`0x3e8`).

If this does not work for your setup, you would need to run as:

```
wsl --distribution ubuntu -u user_name
```

For more information see :

- [Export and Import WSL Linux Distro in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/blog/export-import-wsl-linux-distro-windows-10/)
- [Set Default User for WSL in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/blog/set-default-user-wsl-windows-10/).

Comment: The copy made with `wsl --import` does not contain that executable.
I did `wsl --export Ubuntu UbuntuFile`, then `wsl --import Ubuntu2 UbuntuDirectory UbuntuFile`. The contents of `UbuntuDirectory` are `rootfs`, `temp`, `fsserver` and `UbuntuFile`. No executable.

Comment: Yes, forgot about it : there's a gotcha with import that means you need to execute it via wsl. I corrected my answer.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I know how to set the user for the original Ubuntu (I have two), and I know how to run the second Ubuntu, but how do I set the user for the second Ubuntu?

Comment: Answer corrected again, hoping that this method applies to your setup. Importing distributions is not ideal.

Comment: Should the UID be in hexadecimal format?

Comment: Whichever mode you are entering in the input.

Comment: @harrymc, imported distributions from a previous laptop (both Debian and Ubuntu) are all I use and I code against Linux every day.  They work fine for me.  I have never had a problem.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: They work, but just a tad harder to use.

Comment: this hint save me when my WSL started defaulting to `root` after some crash

Comment: This is still the only way that worked for me. Launching `ubuntu2204.exe config --default-user myuser` didn't do anything. Does it expect UID "1000" instead of username or what?

Answer (score 5):

Verify the uid of the user that you want to set as default in your **Linux console** by `id`:

```
username@host:~$ id
uid=1000(username) gid=1000(username) groups=1000(username),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),117(netdev),1001(docker)
username@host:~$
```

Verify the distro name in **Powershell** by `wsl -l -v`:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* ubuntu-20.04           Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Edit the registry in **Powershell**:

```
Get-ItemProperty Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\*\ DistributionName | Where-Object -Property DistributionName -eq ubuntu-20.04  | Set-ItemProperty -Name DefaultUid -Value 1000
```

Should be good by now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing some custom distributions in WSL, you will not get a "distroname.exe" command to change the configuration. You may use [LxRunOffline](https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline) to change the default user. This toolset can be installed in Windows using [`choco install lxrunoffline`](https://chocolatey.org/packages/lxrunoffline).

#### Get the default user id of a distro

LxRunOffline allows you get and set the default user id (`uid`) for any installed distributions. For instance, if you have a distro named `newdistro` you may check the default user using `gu` (get default user) and `-n` with the name of the distribution:

```
lxrunoffline gu -n newdistro
```

The command returns a number, the user id of the default user:

- the `root` user has the `0` user-id
- the default user created during the install has the `1000` user id.

#### Set the default user id for a distro

If you want to set the `root` as the default user, you can make it using `su` (set default user) with `-n` and the name of the distro, and `-v` with the user id, i.e., `0` for the `root`.

```
lxrunoffline su -n newdistro -v 0
```

Comment: Note that LxRunOffline ultimately does the same thing as the original answer - Set the registry key.  However, the Microsoft recommended way is via `/etc/wsl.conf` (see my answer).

Comment: You are right. I typically use `lxrunoffline` to support old versions of WSL running on Windows LTSB machines (that you cannot upgrade). I think  using `/etc/wsl.conf` is a more elegant solution than `lxrunoffline` in Windows Build 17093 and later

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **[Windows Terminal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/)** then you can configure a profile for your distribution.

In the **Profiles** settings for **Windows Terminal** select your distro's profile, then click the General Tab and under `Command line` you can use one of the previously recommended options for the `wsl` command.

For example, if you named your Profile `Ubuntu` and your username is `bob`, then you would set `Command line` to `wsl.exe -d Ubuntu -u bob`

While you're at it, you can configure the `Starting directory`, aka the one opened by default when you open a terminal for your distro with:

`\\wsl$\Distro\home\username`

Using the previous example, for a distro named `Ubuntu` and a username of `bob`, you would set `Starting directory` to:

`\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\bob`

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me on Windows 11 with an imported Ubuntu distribution. This is more than likely because my user is a domain user rather than local.

What worked is:

1. Go into regedit and search for *Lxss* via Ctrl+F
2. If it comes up with something like this:
   [image]
   Then edit *DefaultUid* and change the value to your user id from the distribution in my case it is 3e8 Hexadecimal and 1000 Decimal
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

Normally went to the root user terminal edit the .bashrc

```
vim .bashrc
```

Append this line to the last of it

```
su - $name
```

Comment: A problem with your solution is that you can use `wsl` to execute scripts and pipelines in Windows. I think that your solution only works if the user enter to the Linux environment. Changing the WSL configuration is a better alternative.  You may check the [WSL documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config) and many other tools, such as  [WSLU](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu) and  [`lxrunoffline`](https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline)

Answer (score -1):

Just FYI, if you have installed distrubution other than ubuntu on WSL like OracleLinux, then command is:

```
OracleLinux91.exe config --default-user root
```

Comment: Thsi doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I am sorry @Toto but question is to "How to set default user for manually installed WSL distro?"
and by this command on WSL, you can definitely do that  OracleLinux91.exe config --default-user root