# What version of WDDM does a Quadro P3000 have?

Tags: wsl2, nvidia-quadro

I have a HP Zbook G3 15.  It has a Quadro M2000M GPU which is fine for my monitors but where it lacks is in the WSL/Linux department.  To get GPU acceleration within WSL I need a card with WDDM 2.9 support.  Unfortunately the M2000M is WDDM 2.7.  This particular models was baked in 2015.

Looking online it appears that a Quadro P3000 might fit (MXM-B vs MXM-A). This is a card from 2017.  I am trying to find if this card has WDDM 2.9 support.

Does it have WDDM 2.9 support?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? WDDM is primarily dependent on the version of Windows. WSLg is hardware dependent. You will also need a supported driver for that version of Windows. You should focus on hardware that supports the version of Window your using.

Comment: I am running windows 10 10.0.19045.  I am fairly sure that the card that came out after the M2000M will have a driver for Windows 10 since the M2000M has one already.  All I need to know is if the driver is WDDM 2.9.

Comment: So WDDM 2.9 was never publicly released. How did you determine you need WDDM 2.9 support? WSLg only supports certain nvidia hardware.

Comment: Just in case, are you looking for CUDA support or for [SR-IOV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-root_input/output_virtualization)?

Comment: No, just OpenGL hardware support.

Answer (score 2):

[Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Display_Driver_Model)
is a function of the Windows version that you're using in which the
graphics driver is installed.

WDDM is not dependent upon the card or upon the driver, as the
driver needs to conform to its operating environment.

WDDM 2.9 was an intermediate version that was included in
Windows 10 Insider Preview "Iron", which was a precursor to
Windows 11.
Windows 11 RTM Final Retail release (version 21H2) already included
WDDM 3.0.

The Intel article
[Understanding the Intel Graphics Driver Version Number](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005654/graphics.html)
summarizes the WDDM versions in the following table:

| **Identifier** | **Operating System (WDDM version)** |
| --- | --- |
| **31** | Windows 11* - WDDM 3.1 |
| **30** | Windows 11* - WDDM 3.0 |
| **27** | Windows® 10 May 2020 Update - WDDM 2.7 |
| **26** | Windows® 10 May 2019 Update - WDDM 2.6 |
| **25** | Windows® 10 October 2018 Update - WDDM 2.5 |
| **24** | Windows® 10 April 2018 Update - WDDM 2.4 |
| **23** | Windows® 10 Fall Creators Update - WDDM 2.3 |
| **22** | Windows® 10 Creators Update - WDDM 2.2 |
| **21** | Windows® 10 Anniversary Update - WDDM 2.1 |
| **20** | Windows® 10 - WDDM 2.0 |
| **10** | Windows 8.1* - WDDM 1.3 |
| **9** | Windows 8* - WDDM 1.2 |
| **8** | Windows 7* - WDDM 1.1 |

Comment: Thanks for that @harrymc.  However I prefer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Display_Driver_Model for the list.  It still doesn't answer my question as does the Quadro P3000 drivers have at least WDDM 2.9 conformity?

Comment: It depends on the Windows version, not on the card. For WDDM 2.9+ you'll need a Windows 11 driver. My current NVIDIA driver on Windows 11 runs in WDDM 3.1 (you can see that by running `dxdiag` in Display tab). Searching for an [NVIDIA Driver Downloads](https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx) for the Quadro P3000 comes up with version [551.86](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/223432/en-us/) from 2024.3.19  which supports Windows 11. Your Windows needs to be version 11 to use WDDM 3.1.

Comment: Not according to this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1754504/how-to-turn-on-gpu-acceleration-in-wsl.  Unfortunately running `(Get-ComputerInfo).WindowsUBR doesn't return anything for me even with admin rights.  However Windows Update history says I have version 22H2 installed plus all the cumulative updates for it.

Comment: Your Windows 10 10.0.19045 is actually 22H2. You then have WDDM 2.7. You can verify that using `dxdiag`, and look in the Display tab.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, with a notebook GPU, and a Quadro at that, you may find driver support to be slow. However, it would appear that the [latest available driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/223432/en-us/) for the Quadro M2000M is in fact a WDDM 3.1 driver. Maybe upgrading the driver is enough.

WSLg is supposedly available on Windows 10. I recommend you ask a new question specifically about getting it to work, with the exact steps you performed and the exact error messages you encountered. Make sure to [check the official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps).

---

WDDM (Windows Display Driver Model) is an interface between the graphics driver and the operating system. It is *not* a hardware property (WDDM 2.7 is already 5 years more recent than your GPU) and a driver is *not necessarily using the latest version*.

You can read about how the driver signals this version [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/wddm-2-1-features#driver-versioning):

> […] To be consistent with the prevailing file versioning requirements for legacy operating systems, file version formatting must follow an AA.BB.CCCCC.DDDDD pattern where:
>
> - AA indicates the driver model version of the most capable device listed in the .inf
> - […]
>
> […]
> Values for AA field:
>
> | Driver Model | AA value |
> | --- | --- |
> | WDDM v2.1 | 21 |
> | WDDM v2.0 | 20 |
> | WDDM v1.3 | 10 |
> | WDDM v1.2 | 9 |
> | WDDM v1.1 | 8 |
> | WDDM v1.0 | 7 |
> | XDDM | 6 |

More recent versions are unfortunately not listed. However, on Windows 11 with WDDM 3.1 (according to `dxdiag`), I have major version 31, so its probably just following the scheme.

What the driver uses and what the operating system supports can differ. There’s probably more sophisticated negotiation when the driver is initialized.

Comment: I had upgraded the driver to the latest version before posting.

Comment: I have WDDM 2.7 drivers as well on my work Windows 10 22H2 device and WSLg works with that. Something else is wrong, as such I recommend asking a new question specifically about getting WSLg to work.

Comment: WSL works - I can run windowed apps and opengl gears but as it is software only.  No hardware acceleration.