# Running WSL that was installed from the Microsoft Store results in "Windows version 10.0.19045.2251 does not support the packaged version of ..."

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed the latest WSL from the Microsoft Store on Windows 10 22H2, but when I attempt to run it, the result is:

```
Windows version 10.0.19045.2251 does not support the packaged version of Windows Subsystem for Linux.
For information please visit https://aka.ms/wslinstall
Press any key to continue...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of WSL is now generally-available as an application package that you can install from the Microsoft Store or via `Add-AppxPackage` using a download from the [WSL Releases page](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases).

WSL application package (Store) releases are now able run on Windows 10 but do require that you are on Windows UBR (update build revision) 2311 or later.  That's the last 4 digits of your Windows build number, as in `19045.2311` (for Windows 10 22H2).  You can determine the UBR by running `(Get-ComputerInfo).WindowsUBR` in PowerShell.

Note that [some users report](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/9107) a slightly different error depending on their Windows build or WSL release.  For instance:

```
The packaged version of WSL is not supported by windows-version 10.0.19045.2130
```

Currently, 2311 can be installed via [KB5020030](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/november-15-2022-kb5020030-os-builds-19042-2311-19043-2311-19044-2311-and-19045-2311-preview-237a9048-f853-4e29-a3a2-62efdbea95e2), an optional update above-and-beyond Windows 11 22H2.  Those on on corporate systems managed by IT may need to wait another month or so for a "non-Preview" UBR, but others should be able to install it by:

- First, making sure your system is otherwise completely up-to-date.
- Going to *Settings* -> *Check for Updates* and press the *Check for Updates* button.
- If you are fully updated on Windows 10 (but still running *less than* UBR 2311) you should see *"2022-11 Cumulative Update Preview for Windows 10 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5020030)"* available as an optional update.  Install it and reboot when prompted.

After rebooting, since you already had installed the WSL Application Package, it should immediately start working now that your system is on 2311 or later.  You can confirm version info from PowerShell with:

```
> (Get-ComputerInfo).WindowsUBR
2311 # or later

> wsl --version
WSL version: 1.0.0.0
Kernel version: 5.15.74.2
WSLg version: 1.0.47
MSRDC version: 1.2.3575
Direct3D version: 1.606.4
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19045.2311
```

If you receive the Help text when running `wsl --version`, then you still don't have access to the WSL app package.  Try:

```
wsl --update
```

If WSL is not installed, change to an elevated administrative PowerShell and try:

```
wsl --install
```

And if it is installed, try uninstalling the app (from *Add or remove programs*) and reinstalling from the Store.