# Create WSL2 instance from VHDX

Tags: wsl2, vhdx

I copied the VHDX file (called `ext4.vhdx` as usual) for a WSL2 instance to a new machine. How can I use this for a new WSL2 instance?

Answer (score 15):

*Short answer:*

```
wsl --import-in-place <new_distro_name> <path_to_vhdx>
```

*More detail:*

I've rewritten this answer for the latest version of WSL, since it is now available for (most) Windows 10 and (all) Windows 11 users.  If you are on an earlier version of WSL and can't upgrade for some reason, then please see the [edit history](https://superuser.com/revisions/1667985/2) of this answer for an older method that you can try.

First, make sure you are on WSL 1.0.0 or later.  You can install it from the [Microsoft Store](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage).  Windows 10 users, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1418934/1165986) for instructions on how to install the prerequisites.  It's an unrelated question, but it also requires a recent WSL release.

With 1.0.0 or later in place, to reuse a `ext4.vhdx` on a new computer:

- Place your `ext4.vhdx` in the directory you want to use for the distribution.  For instance, `C:\Users\<youruser>\WSL\ubuntu_22.04`.  The name of the directory doesn't matter here.
- From PowerShell:

  ```
  wsl --import-in-place <new_distro_name> <path_to_vhdx>
  # For example
  # wsl --import-in-place ubuntu_22.04 C:\Users\ntd\WSL\ubuntu_22.04
  ```

  *Important:*  To avoid "confusing" the distribution installers, I recommend avoiding the distribution names that they would use.  Examples of this include:

  - Ubuntu
  - Ubuntu-20.04
  - Debian
  - Alpine

  This is why I use `ubuntu_22.04` as an example, with the underscore in place of the hyphen.
- Follow the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/a/1627461/1210833) for setting the default username in this new distribution/instance.
- Optionally, use `wsl --set-default <distro>` to set the imported distribution as the default that will run when you just execute `wsl`.  If this is the only distribution, it should automatically be set as default.

Comment: This is so great since you can just copy/move the exact same vhdx and use it rather than other answers I read which talked about exporting and importing, which feels more inefficient