# Error when attempting to create WSL2 from backed up ext4.vhdx file

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, virtual-disk, ubuntu-22.04, vhdx

I've tried the steps [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1667969/create-wsl2-instance-from-vhdx) for using a `ext4.vhdx` file to create a new WSL2 instance, but I'm running into a problem.

The referenced answer:

> - Set up WSL, as usual.  Make sure you do the `wsl --set-default-version 2` step.
> - Install the *same* distribution from the Microsoft Store that you had on the previous machine
> - Run it for the first time, creating the same username as on the previous computer.
> - Exit WSL
> - `wsl --shutdown` from PowerShell or CMD
> - Copy the old `ext4.vhdx` over the newly created one.  I'm guessing you know the location, since you backed it up on the old computer, but it's going to be in `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\<distribution_package>\LocalState`.  If you don't find an `ext4.vhdx`, and instead find a `rootfs` folder, then the distribution was created as WSL1.

So, this is what I tried, with one exception, but I get the following error:

```
The virtual machine or container was forcefully exited.
```

My one exception is that the previous version installed was Ubuntu 22.04.1.6.0, while my newly installed version is 22.04.1.7.0

Is there a way to get 22.04.1.6.0?  Or another fix for my particular error?

The old machine *is over-written* by the new machine, so doing an `wsl --export` isn't an option.

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  Just a heads-up that you can copy the formatting from another post by clicking *Edit* on that post.  Even as a brand new user, you'll have access to that.  I've gone ahead and done that to make the question more readable since I know you didn't know about that trick ;-).

Comment: What's your Windows version?  10?  11?  22H2 of either?  Thanks!

Comment: So you get the error about the virtual machine or container being forcefully exited, but what happens after that, are you unable to start the instance at all? If you had not overwritten the original machine `wsl.exe --update --rollback` might have been an option.

Comment: Also a side-note -- I just rewrote my answer to that linked question, but I don't *think* the changes will make a difference in this area.  And yet, they may ...

Answer (score 0):

> `The virtual machine or container was forcefully exited.`

Hmm.  From [this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5110) there appears to be a *lot* that could cause that.

One suspect is [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5110#issuecomment-656174218):

> Then I do `wsl --shutdown` and if I haven't waited long enough, it would tell me that the program is being used by another process. If I tried again after 1 minute or so, it executes the command. After that, if I try running wsl again, it gives me the same error:

Have you tried again with a longer wait after the `wsl --shutdown`?

Also there's [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5110#issuecomment-649214409):

> I launched the bash on Ubuntu shortcut and there was still some setup to be done.

Make sure that the username and password get set fully.  I'm guessing this isn't the problem, but it falls in the area that you would be hitting by following my original instructions.

---

It might be worth it to try the [new method](https://superuser.com/a/1667985/1210833) I posted today.  It's greatly simplified, and updating your WSL probably can't hurt that chances of the underlying being fixed also.