# Installed Nox on Windows 10, which uninstalled WSL2 and thus my Ubuntu VMs. Are they VMs recoverable?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtual-machine, wsl2

On windows 10. I was unaware WSL2 was tethered to Hyper-V. I installed Nox which said it needed to disable Hyper-V. It did, and asked for a reboot. When I tried to run my WSL2 via terminal it is saying "This application requires the Windows Subsystem for Linux Optional Component.". I still have `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu*\LocalState\ext4.vhdx`. I copied these files just to be safe.

I saw this post: [Create WSL2 instance from VHDX](https://superuser.com/questions/1667969/create-wsl2-instance-from-vhdx), which seems like I could just reinstall WSL2 and use these steps to reinstall from my `ext4.vhdx`. Would this work? I'm worried about somehow messing up my WSL2 VM by a reinstall.

Comment: WSL2 has been installed from the Windows Store for more than 2 years not the optional feature.

Comment: What happens if you uninstall Nox and re-enable Hyper-V and WSL2?

Comment: haven't tried @harrymc, that was my plan, just wanted to sanity check in case i ruin everything

Comment: It's already ruined - nothing to lose. But guard carefully your backup of `ext4.vhdx`.

Comment: Nice. Uninstalled Nox. Reinstalled wsl. Reboot 2x. I still had registry keys so it _just works_ ™