# Why does importing Arch's bootstrap image into WSL2 cause mount errors but importing Arch's Docker image does not?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I recently installed Arch on WSL2 and was wondering why the official bootstrap image import fails but importing an extracted Arch's Docker image works fine.

#### Case 1

- Downloaded the latest bootstrap image from one of the mirrors listed at [archlinux.org](https://archlinux.org).
- Repacked it to get rid of the `root.x86_64` sub-dir with:

  ```
  fakeroot -- bash -c "tar -xf bootstrap.tar.gz && tar -czaf rootfs.tar.gz root.x86_64/*"
  ```
- Moved the `.tar` to the Windows File System
- Imported the `.tar` and ran `wsl -d Arch`. This yielded the following error, rendering the distro useless.

  ```
  Error mounting one of the file systems. Run 'dmesg' for more details.
  ```
- I tried running `dmesg` with `wsl -d Arch --exec dmesg` but was returned the same previous error so couldn't pinpoint the issue.

#### Case 2

- Created a Docker container with the latest Arch image.

  ```
  docker run -t --name arch archlinux ls /
  ```
- Exported it to a tar file.

  ```
  docker export arch -o arch-wsl.tar
  ```
- Imported it. Ran `wsl -d Arch`. And it immediately dropped me into `bash`.

Any idea why do these two cases yield different results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @NotTheDr01ds for taking out time and pointing out the issues with my previous attempt and the resultant `tar`.

I found that using `bsdtar` included with `libarchive` works perfectly, instead of `GNU tar` with `fakeroot`:

```
fakeroot -- bash -c "bsdtar -xf bootstrap.tar.gz  && bsdtar -C root.x86_64 -czaf rootfs.tar.gz ."
```

This results in a perfect import. You can then continue initializing `pacman` keyring and stuff.

As for why `GNU tar` produces warnings, I am not sure. According to [this](http://lifeonubuntu.com/tar-errors-ignoring-unknown-extended-header-keyword/), it is just a compatibility conflict between the two tools. I found a comparison [thread here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101561/what-are-the-differences-between-bsdtar-and-gnu-tar).

Answer (score 2):

*Short answer:*

Your first attempt using the bootstrap image and `fakeroot` is producing an invalid rootfs.  It's not actually removing the `root.x86_64` parent directory.

*More detail:*

The `Error mounting one of the file systems. Run 'dmesg' for more details.`, in my experience, usually means that the archive doesn't contain a valid (to WSL) rootfs.

At first I thought this was due to importing a gzipped file, since the default for `--export` is a simple tar (and you do that in your Docker steps).

However, I just tested with both a `tar` and a `.tar.gz` and it worked for me either way.  I used slightly different steps, though -- Specifically, I used `sudo` rather than `fakeroot` since I'm trying it from an an existing Ubuntu 20.04 distribution.  *Edit*:  I also gave it a try with `fakeroot` under my Artix distribution and found the problem.  See the section below *"Why your fakeroot attempt didn't work"*.

I was successful with the following.  First, from Ubuntu 20.04:

```bsh
wget http://mirror.rackspace.com/archlinux/iso/2022.03.01/archlinux-bootstrap-2022.03.01-x86_64.tar.gz
sudo tar --xattrs -xzvf archlinux-bootstrap-2022.03.01-x86_64.tar.gz
cd root.x86_64/
sudo tar --xattrs -cf ../archtest.tar .
# or
# sudo tar --xattrs -czf ../arch-wsl.tar.gz .
mv ../arch-wsl.tar* /mnt/c/Users/<some_location_in_my_profile>
# I have a standard WSL directory under my Documents folder
```

Then from PowerShell (you are already familiar with these steps, obviously):

```
cd <location_from_above>
mkdir -p instances\arch
wsl --import arch .\instances\arch .\arch-wsl.tar --version 2
wsl ~ -d arch
```

##### Why your fakeroot attempt didn't work

I ran your command-line to try it out under Artix, and I can see the problem.  The tar that is created from it still has the `root.x86_64` in it.  To get rid of it, you need to use the `-C/--directory` option to specify the real root:

```
fakeroot -- bash -c "tar -xf bootstrap.tar.gz && tar -C root.x86_64 -czaf rootfs.tar.gz ."
```

However, there's still a problem with that, since the result archive doesn't have the proper security capability on a few commands:

```
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'
```

Attempting to use `--xattrs` as I did with a simple `sudo` above, still doesn't work, and I'm not sure just why at this point:

```
fakeroot -- bash -c "tar --xattrs -xf bootstrap.tar.gz  && tar --xattrs -C root.x86_64 -czaf rootfs.tar.gz ."
```

Results in:

```
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'
tar: ./usr/bin/newuidmap: Unknown file type; file ignored
tar: ./usr/bin/newgidmap: Unknown file type; file ignored
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

If you can figure out why that's failing under `fakeroot`, let me know.  But the `sudo` version works just fine for me.

##### A few side-notes:

- After creating your default user, you'll want to set it as the WSL default user using [these steps](https://superuser.com/a/1627461/1210833).
- Arch is still a Systemd distribution, and (as you may already know), Systemd is not well supported under WSL due to (a) WSL's `/init` system which sets up the WSL/Windows integration, and (b) Systemd's requirement that it be PID1.

  I quickly migrated from Arch to Artix, as the latter is a Systemd-free Arch-based distro.  I'm still "early" (been on it about a month), but the results are encouraging.  Artix supports 5 different alternative process supervisors, and has scripts/unit files for most all services installed through `pacman` (but not, however, AUR).  If you want to go this route, let me know, and I can share my setup instructions.

Comment: Thanks! I faced those header warnings as well. However, I ignored them since unpacking was successful in spite of them. And it was sloppy of me to not check the archive first.

Comment: Using `bsdtar` instead of `GNU tar` fixed the header warning though. And it works perfectly under `fakeroot` now.

Comment: I would appreciate you sharing your Artix setup ;)

Comment: @Aniket Yup, and I should have remembered to try `bsdtar` since it handles extended attributes by default.  As I said, it's not a huge deal for them to be missing -- You *could* just set those attributes manually, but I do think it's much better to capture them in the tar, of course.  For Artix, I'm working on documenting it.  I'll ping you in a comment when I get it finished up.  Have one or two other things to write up first.