# How to restore WSL2 files from an HDD backup (not `wsl --export` backup)?

Tags: windows, backup, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I had a nasty Windows 10 update problem locking myself out of my Windows installation. Unfortunately, I had no Windows backups.

I ended up loading into my dual-boot Ubuntu, making a backup of the whole Windows HDD with dc3dd, re-installing the Windows, and then restoring the dc3dd backup into a separate partition.

With that, I can now access all the old Windows files from the new Windows installation.

But I had some important projects within the WSL2 Ubuntu on the old Windows, which I would like to restore. Obviously, if I had wsl --export backups - this wouldn't be a problem, but I don't.

As far as I understand, it's not as simple as finding them somewhere deep in the old filesystem because they live in some sort of a virtual machine file.

So how can I approach this?

Thank you

Comment: You can probably install the same distro and replace the vhdx with the old one afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward now for WSL2.

1. First, you'll need to find the `ext4.vhdx` files from those distributions.  If you installed the distribution from the Microsoft Store, then they will be under:

   ```
   <backed_up_drive>\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\<package_name>\LocalState\ext4.vhdx
   ```

   For Ubuntu distributions, the package name will start with "Canonical".

   Move the `ext4.vhdx` file to a location on the new system.  I use something like:

   ```
   $ENV:userprofile\WSL\instances\Ubuntu_22.04_WSL2_Shkarik
   ```
2. Next, make sure that you have the latest Windows 10 updates installed.  You should then be able to install WSL *itself* from the Microsoft Store using [this page](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage).  That's a later release release of WSL than comes with Windows 10, and it has the `--import-in-place` option.
3. With the new WSL installed, open PowerShell (as a regular user, *not* Admin), navigate to the directory where you placed the `ext4.vhdx` and:

   ```
   # Import
   # wsl --import-in-place <new_distro_name> <path_to_vhdx>

   wsl --import-in-place Ubuntu_22.04_WSL2_Shkarik ./ext4.vhdx

   # Optionally, set it as the default, if there are any others installed
   wsl --set-default Ubuntu_22.04_WSL2_Shkarik

   # Start it with:
   wsl ~
   # or
   wsl ~ -d Ubuntu_22.04_WSL2-Shkarik
   ```
4. Once inside the distribution, you'll be the root user.  You can set your default user per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1627461/1210833).

Alternatively, you can just reinstall Ubuntu, then copy the old `ext4.vhdx` over the new one.  However, I prefer being able to choose my own location and name for the distribution (per above).  It also lets you quickly install another copy (for testing) with `ubuntu.exe` without interfering with your "day-to-day" files.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to try it, but I finally did and it's worked like a charm!
Thank you so much!

P.S.
For the future readers of this answer, maybe you should consider changing the step 3 a little bit to mention that the first argument for the `wsl --import-in-place` is a desired distro name. It got me a little confused because it's the name of the folder from your example. I had to google it to clarify.

Comment: Good to hear it!  And that's a good point - I've added a description of the arguments.  Thanks!