# wsl --import and --import-in-place appear to operate, but the result is a fresh OS

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm migrating to a new work machine. Old machine is wsl2 but apparently a slightly older version. It doesn't have `-vhd` flag on import or export. Both machines, before and after, show appropriate output from `wsl -l -v`.

I ran export. Using 7zip, I see that the exported tar contains the filesystem as it existed before export. As a separate measure, I also found and copied the vhdx.

I've put them both on the new machine.

I have imported the exported tar, and also used import-in-place with the copied vhdx. They both end with "The operation completed successfully" and show as separate items on the `wsl -l -v`

However, neither of them are the filesystem from the exported or copied original on the old machine. Logging into the 2 different instances, then using `ls -al`, shows that the ~ dir looks exactly like the original Ubuntu install that came with the `wsl --install` command on the new machine... It's basically a fresh OS. I don't think it's different pointers to the same virtual drive, as the `cat /etc/os-release` is different for each one, as is the command history.

What I need is to move the used distro, as is, from the old machine to the new one. Complete with os and filesystem.

Did I miss something? If so is there documentation for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default user was set to `root@`. I looked at `/home/myname` and there was my home dir contents.

I used this [Super User answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1566022/how-to-set-default-user-for-manually-installed-wsl-distro) to set the default user. The file system appears as expected.