# WSL seems to ignore "default user" argument when updating distro

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

We are creating a deployment for WSL/Ubuntu 20.04. This works flawlessly for virgin machines.

However, we have a population of machines which have Ubuntu 16.04 which we want to update. We're not in the least concerned about any user-level data, as WSL is used simply as a tool for loading structural models.

Here's the CMD we run on the target machines:

```
wsl --terminate Ubuntu-16.04
wsl --unregister Ubuntu-16.04
wsl --unregister Ubuntu-20.04
powershell Add-AppxPackage -Path '[path_to_AppX]\Ubuntu_2004.2021.825.0_x64.appx'
ubuntu --install --root
```

After installing, that last command causes the distro to prompt for the creation of a default UNIX account. It does NOT do this on virgin machines. It simply exits.

Comment: So what version of WSL do you have installed? The one installed through the Optional Windows Feature or the Windows Store? You can do one of two things, use `config --default-user root` to specify you want to use `root` or use [`/etc/wsl.conf`](https://superuser.com/questions/1566022/how-to-set-default-user-for-manually-installed-wsl-distro) to specify the default user. Your command attempts to specify `root` as the user but I don't believe that syntax is current or accurate. [The](https://superuser.com/questions/1566022/) would suggest your syntax is wrong.

Comment: Did you include the full cmd? You normally specify a path where it ends, like `--root "c:\custom\folder"`.

Answer (score 0):

There was some inconsistency.  The command isn't:

```
ubuntu --install --root
```

but

```
ubuntu install --root
```