# Installing Ubuntu on /mnt/d with WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

```
OS: Windows 11
```

I installed WSL on my Windows 11 Pro and loaded Ubuntu 20.04, as follows (from a Command Prompt run as administrator):

```
wsl --install Ubuntu-20.04
```

The install completed without any errors. I then exited the Ubuntu session, and landed on:

```
c:\windows\system32
```

I then typed:

```
wsl
```

And ended up in an Ubuntu terminal session:

```
john@john-x5700: /mnt/c/Windows/system32
```

I have two disks: C and D. appearing in the Ubuntu terminal as:

```
/mnt/c
```

and

```
/mnt/d
```

It appears as if Ubuntu was installed on /mnt/c. What I would like to do, is have Ubuntu install in /mnt/d. Is this possible?

Comment: Your question would be sound.. but I don't understand what you are actually trying to do.  Sure you can install your distros "[elsewhere](https://vpraharsha3.medium.com/installing-wsl-distro-to-a-different-custom-location-30d101f04113)" but the phrasing of your question makes me inclined to think that you don't understand the file system.  From WSLs point of view, it is installed to "/" (root) and not one of the drives you mention (from a logical point of view).  Those are mount points to your windows drives.  Perhaps I am wrong.  Please explain what you are trying to accomplish. :)

Comment: The question is: I want Ubuntu to install in /mnt/d and not /mnt/c.

Comment: To install to "D: drive" see https://superuser.com/questions/1572834/is-there-any-way-to-install-wsl-on-non-c-drive, to move to D: drive see https://superuser.com/questions/1550622/move-wsl2-file-system-to-another-drive

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before getting into how to move/install a WSL distribution on another drive, it's important to understand a few things.

First, when you run just `wsl` (without any options) from PowerShell or CMD (or anywhere, really) that tells WSL to start in whatever directory the parent process passes in to it.  If you are in `C:\Windows\System32` in CMD, then that's where it will start.

So your WSL *starting directory* has nothing to do with where your WSL instance is *installed*.

You can override the starting directory in one of several ways:

- `wsl ~`:  Will start in the home directory of the default user in the filesystem in WSL.  For WSL2, that directory is in a *virtual* disk.
- `wsl --cd /`:  Will start in the root directory of that virtual filesystem.
- `wsl --cd C:\`:  Will start in the root of the Windows `C:` drive, which is mounted at `/mnt/c` by default, as you've already found.  This is a *mount point* in the virtual filesystem to a real (likely) physical drive that is actually exposed through an internal WSL network.

All of these commands will work the same regardless of where your actual Ubuntu distribution is installed.

So really, you don't want to move it to `/mnt/d`; you want to move it to somewhere on `D:`.

###### So where is Ubuntu installed?

That *virtual disk* that I mentioned is really the bulk of the Ubuntu installation in WSL.  It contains the entire Linux (technically, "ext4") filesystem where all your files *inside* WSL are stored.

The virtual disk is automatically installed into:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Canonical<...>\LocalState\ext4.vhdx
```

That should be something like:

```
C:\Users\<your_windows_user>\AppData\Local\Packages\Canonical<...>\LocalState\ext4.vhdx
```

Warning -- Do not attempt to move this manually.

###### So how can I move it or change where it is installed?

*Technically*, you can't "move it" or "change where it is installed", but as a perfectly acceptable workaround, you can:

- Make a backup of your existing Ubuntu installation
- Restore it to whatever directory you want (on the `D:\` drive in this case)
- Remove the original

To do that:

- First, in PowerShell, create the following directory structure somewhere on your `D:` drive:

  ```
  mkdir D:\WSL\instances\Ubuntu2004
  mkdir D:\WSL\images
  cd D:\WSL\images
  ```
- Then, while still in the `images` directory:

  ```
  wsl --export Ubuntu-20.04 ubuntu.tar
  wsl --import Ubuntu2004 D:\WSL\instances\Ubuntu2004 ubuntu.tar --version 2
  ```

  The first line creates the backup, and the second creates a new WSL instance named `Ubuntu2004` (instead of the default `Ubuntu-20.04`) on your `D:` drive.
- Start your new instance via:

  ```
  wsl ~ -d Ubuntu2004
  ```
- WSL doesn't "remember" the default user for an `--import`'d instance, so you should be `root` at the moment.  You'll need to set your default username for this instance per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1627461/1210833).  Namely:

  ```
  sudo -e /etc/wsl.conf
  ```

  And add the following:

  ```
  [user]
  default=<your_username>
  ```
- Save, exit, and exit Ubuntu.
- `wsl --terminate Ubuntu2004`
- `wsl ~ -d Ubuntu2004`
- If everything is working as expected, then set that instance as your default.  Again, back in PowerShell:

  ```
  wsl --set-default Ubuntu2004
  ```
- Now, when you type `wsl ~` you will start in that instance, as you can confirm by running `wsl -l -v` (again, from PowerShell) and/or `echo $WSL_DISTRO_NAME` (from inside Ubuntu).
- Once you have **confirmed** that everything is working as intended, you can remove the original with:

  ```
  wsl --unregister Ubuntu-20.04
  ```

  Remember, this is a **destructive** operation and will remove all files in that virtual filesystem.

Of course, even though this is now installed under the `D:\WSL` directory, unless you specify the directory when starting (via something like `wsl ~` or one of the other methods mentioned), you are still going to start in whatever directory the parent process passes in (e.g. `C:\Windows\System32`).

One *great* advantage of this technique is that, once you learn it, you can install multiple distributions.  You can easily create a copy of your existing Ubuntu installation, try something out in it, and then get rid of the "temporary" copy.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. You should publish it as your own blog entry.

Comment: Amazing answer sir!  Not only was I too lazy to answer, your answer is better than mine would have even been! :)

Comment: Thanks @SeñorCMasMas (and @EastsideDev) -- I have the advantage of doing this workflow *very* often myself. :-)