# WSL-2 distro network speed is capped at 30-40 Mbps

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Recently installed Ubuntu and Kali-linux distro on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2) on different drive as per this [stackoverflow question](https://superuser.com/questions/1572834/is-there-any-way-to-install-wsl-on-non-c-drive) manually. The issue is that the network speed is capped at 30–40 Mbps, but I have a network bandwidth with up to 150 Mbps. This is the same across any application on both the distros. On installing a WSL distro using the wsl-command in PowerShell (distro is installed to the Windows Drive), there is no network issue and the speed is not capped, and full bandwidth is used.

**System Info**

OS : Windows 11 Home
C:/ Windows Drive [Disk 1 SSD]
D:/ Data Drive    [Disk 2 HDD, Partition 1]
K:/ Data Drive    [Disk 2 HDD, Partition 2] [WSL Distros installed here]

There is a separate Virtual network interface for WSL created, and **this interface is not present in the control panel network adapters section**.

`ipconfig` gives the following output:

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9656:d028:8652:66b6%64
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.21.144.1
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

What is the reason for this behaviour (low network speed)?
Is there any way this can be fixed by modifying the vEthernet NIC settings?

Comment: There is a very long thread here with various recommendations like: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8171#issuecomment-1572881486 or https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4901#issuecomment-1511986790. The most common ones seem to be enable network sharing (wi-fi only) like `netsh int ipv4 set interface "Wi-Fi" forwarding=enable` every time you connect to wifi, or disabling "Large Send Offload" for whatever reason. If you've narrowed it down to installing on another drive, then you might want to post over there