# How to change default disk WSL2 uses to store images?

Tags: wsl2

Here is many answers how to [move existent image to another drive](https://superuser.com/questions/1550622/move-wsl2-file-system-to-another-drive), but I couldn't find how to set another drive as default for new image [installations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install#install-wsl-command) (**install != import**).

Is it possible?

Comment: How are you installing WSL 2 distributions? From Microsoft Store?

Comment: @DanielB - Installing from the Windows Store is the only way to get the current version of WSL2. You can install WSL2 on another disk like any other UWP application.

Comment: I specifically referred to WSL 2 _distributions_, because that’s what OP is trying to put elsewhere. They can come from Microsoft Store or can be imported manually using `wsl import`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move WSL2 file system to another drive](https://superuser.com/questions/1550622/move-wsl2-file-system-to-another-drive)

Comment: @harrymc Did you check link in my question and explanation why this is not an answer?

Comment: @DanielB I mentioned that here is couple solutions how to **import** images in other drive. However that is not the same as **install**. Some settings and information is lost during export → import. I want to use `wsl --install`. Currently I used [this way](https://superuser.com/a/1572837/1263318) to be able do clean install on D drive. But that is a workaround, not a solution.