WSL won't install after upgrading to Windows 11 24H2
I am running the current Dev Windows 11 build (version 24H2 OS Build 26100.1).  Ever since I upgraded from 23H2 to 24H2 I've been unable to get WSL to work.  When I run "wsl.exe" I get the following message:
Windows Subsystem for Linux must be updated to the latest version to proceed. You can update by running 'wsl.exe --update'.
For more information please visit https://aka.ms/wslinstall

Press any key to install Windows Subsystem for Linux.
Press CTRL-C or close this window to cancel.
This prompt will time out in 60 seconds.

When I run "wsl.exe --install" or "wsl.exe --update", I get this:
Downloading: Windows Subsystem for Linux 2.1.5
Installing: Windows Subsystem for Linux 2.1.5
Catastrophic failure

I've tried uninstalling the distro (Ubuntu), uninstalling WSL from the Windows features screen (from Programs and Features in Control Panel), making sure "New apps will save to" is set to C: drive (where "\Windows" is located) in Settings > System > Storage > Advanced storage settings > Where new content is saved ... and rebooted between each step during several attempts and nothing changes.  Everything else on my system works fine, it's just WSL and this only started when I upgraded to 24H2.  I can't get any more information that "Catastrophic failure" ("--verbose" adds nothing).  I've even tried installing a Linux kernel manually and it tells me I already have a newer version of WSL installed.  I have tried basically everything that is suggested by any Google result I can find and nothing works.
UPDATE:
After unchecking "Windows Subsystem for Linux" in Programs and Features under Control Panel and rebooting.
Next, I moving all the WindowsApps that were installed in "D:\WndowsApps" back to "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" with the "Move" option for each app under Apps > Installed apps in Settings.
I was able to then take ownership (change ownership to "Administrators" and then take "Full control" with my account) of all the directories (and their contents) that contained "Linux" or "Ubuntui" in their names.
I then delete them.
Afterwards, there was nothing installed under "D:\WindowsApps", so I changed the ownership of it to Administrators and then delete it entirely.
I rebooted after doing all this.
I then ran Windows Update and rebooted.
Then, I tried to reinstall WSL and it failed with the same "Catastrophic failure" message.
When I checked D: drive afterwards, Windows had recreated "D:\WindowsApps" and tried to install it there instead of on C: drive which is where  "Where new content is saved" is pointing.  Something is set somewhere (I presume in the Registry) telling Windows to try to install it on D: drive which, according to various Google results, will always fail as WSL must be installed on the same drive as C:\Windows.
Does anyone know what I need to update in the Registry to make Windows install WSL on C: drive?

Try running netsh winsock reset as an Administrator, reboot the system, then run as a normal user wsl --update and wsl --install

Did that and rebooted after (more than once).  It didn't do anything.

Install the MSI for the current preview release or post a screenshot of the error within Event Log for the log Microsoft-Windows-AppXDeploymentServer/Operational. If the MSI does it work, report the issue to Microsoft, and downgrade to 23H2.  This might require reinstalling Windows since you are on an Insider Preview build.

Excellent! "I am running the current Dev Windows 11 build." You are therefore a beta tester, you have found a bug, and you should report that to Microsoft, in a manner describing what caused the issue, so that it can be fixed before release. If a contributor here were to fix it for you, you would have a working v. 24H2 Build 26100.1, but others would not.

The error from Event View is as follows:
The following packages will be installed: MicrosoftWindows.UndockedDevKit_10.0.26100.1_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy . The following packages will be removed: MicrosoftWindows.UndockedDevKit_10.0.22000.1_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy

I submitted a bug report through the Feedback Hub.  I have no idea if I will every hear back from those guys again.

Please see the update I just added above.

To answer your updated question, perhaps reviewing how you told WSL to install to D drive and then reversing those steps would work. Here's a guide for moving WSL to D drive, and it may help provide clues for what you did: https://superuser.com/questions/1572834/is-there-any-way-to-install-wsl-on-non-c-drive

Does this answer your question? Change of WSL installation location
