# What is the best way to be able to use WSL on both my local C: drive and my external D: drive?

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am using Ubuntu on WSL, which I downloaded a few months ago. However, my storage space on my local SSD (only 256 GB) filled up very quickly. I now have a 2TB external SSD, to which I would like to move my files. I want to be able to use WSL locally still, but just move the large amount of data I have on my local drive to my external SSD.

I tried downloading my /home folder of Ubuntu as a .tar file, moving it over to the D: drive, and then unpacking it. However, now when I try and do nearly anything in my original instance of Ubuntu it will not work. I have tried downloading a separate instance of Ubuntu, and that works fine (but has no files in it because it is a new instance). However, my original instance no longer works.

So, what I know is that I have a copy of all the data I care about (the /home dir which has been moved to the D: drive). I am willing to do a fresh instance if that is what's best. But, I am looking forward here: What is the best way (essentially what would a very experienced WSL user do) to have these two separate instances?

Comment: You might try creating a symbolic link from the extra drive to your home directory to give yourself more space.  I have done it many times.

Comment: Just for the future, moving Linux file system directories ("folder" is Win/MacOS lingo) is often a bit more complex process than just copying them over. Before diving into this kind of action it's a good idea to search for how it's supposed to be done. The good news is that as long as the original installation boots and you can login, your `/home` can probably be restored... and @SeñorCMasMas got there faster :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, do restore the tarball of your home directory back into the existing distribution.  To do so, start your distribution with:

```
wsl ~ -u root
```

IIRC, `tar` extract as root will extract the files as the original user that created the tarball.

Once the distribution is working correctly again, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1771436/1210833) for how to move the distribution to the other drive safely.